# Can I use Zookeeper 3.7.1 with Solr 7.7.3?

Tags: solr, zookeeper

Each version of Solr ships with a version of Zookeeper.  Solr's docs say that you should upgrade Zookeeper if you upgrade Solr, but can you upgrade Zookeeper to a later version that is shipped with Solr *without* upgrading Solr?  The specific version I'm looking at is having Solr 7.7.3 use external Zookeeper 3.7.1 rather than the ZK 3.4 it comes with, since 3.4 is EOL and 3.7 is supported.
I searched for ages in the Solr docs but I couldn't find the answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer from a colleague immediately after posting this - Solr *only* supports the version of Zookeeper it ships with.  Solr is only tested with that one version of Zookeeper, and Zookeeper makes breaking changes regularly, so any other version than the one that Solr ships with is likely to have issues or not work.